# PowerBI: Date and Date time Filter Using URL Parameter in report

Tags: powerbi, query-string

I am Using power bi online for using date and DateTime slicer in the report. when I'm using slicer than the powerbi slicer will be working fine. but when the same thing will using via passing the query in URL **URL?filter=Table/Date eq '2018-02-19 14:48:35.020'** then it will not be working. please suggest if I missed anything or I will be taking wrong approach or syntax.

or if the same thing I will enter for any other values it will be working fine.
but issue occurs only for Date and DateTime ranges or particular single date selections.

Answer (score 0):

In Slicer has two date values i.e. fromDate and TODate.. so here your are filtering Two dates with one syntax which is not supported in PowerBI now.

You can check below PowerBI URL Filter Limitation here

[PowerBI URL Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters)